# How can I find out why a WordPress theme breaks my website?

Tags: php

I recently got a theme on WordPress and when setting up the theme I tried to use the Twitter functionality, although this part of the code for me to embed one of my tweets into the page would break the website.

All of the API tokens have been added into previous sections of the code as well, which makes me think something is wrong and that there is probably a syntax error.

```
 <?php
            function buildBaseString($baseURI, $method, $params) {
                $r = array();
                ksort($params);
                foreach($params as $key=>$value){
                    $r[] = "$key=" . rawurlencode($value);
                }
                return $method."&" . rawurlencode($baseURI) . '&' . rawurlencode(implode('&', $r));
            }

            function buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth) {
                $r = 'Authorization: OAuth ';
                $values = array();
                foreach($oauth as $key=>$value)
                    $values[] = "$key=\"" . rawurlencode($value) . "\"";
                $r .= implode(', ', $values);
                return $r;
            }

            $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

            $oauth_access_token = $tweet_token;
            $oauth_access_token_secret = $tweet_token_secret;
            $consumer_key = $tweet_key;
            $consumer_secret = $tweet_key_secret;

            $oauth = array( 'screen_name' => $tweet_user,
                            'count' => 1,
                            'oauth_consumer_key' => $consumer_key,
                            'oauth_nonce' => time(),
                            'oauth_signature_method' => 'HMAC-SHA1',
                            'oauth_token' => $oauth_access_token,
                            'oauth_timestamp' => time(),
                            'oauth_version' => '1.0');

            $base_info = buildBaseString($url, 'GET', $oauth);
            $composite_key = rawurlencode($consumer_secret) . '&' . rawurlencode($oauth_access_token_secret);
            $oauth_signature = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $base_info, $composite_key, true));
            $oauth['oauth_signature'] = $oauth_signature;

            // Make Requests
            $header = array(buildAuthorizationHeader($oauth), 'Expect:');
            $options = array( CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
                              //CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
                              CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
                              CURLOPT_URL => $url . '?screen_name='.$tweet_user.'&count=1', 
                              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                              CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false);

            $feed = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
            $json = curl_exec($feed);
            curl_close($feed);

            $twitter_data = json_decode($json);

            $out ='<ul id="twitter">';

            foreach ($twitter_data as $key=>$value) {
            $regex = '@((https?://)?([-\w]+\.[-\w\.]+)+\w(:\d+)?(/([-\w/_\.\,]*(\?\S+)?)?)*)@';
            $text  = $value->text;
            $text  = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\./-]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', '<a target="blank" title="$1" href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
            $text  = preg_replace('/#([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/', "<a target='blank' title='$1' href=\"http://twitter.com/search?q=$1\">#$1</a>",  $text);
            $text  = preg_replace("/@([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/", "<a target='blank' title='$1' href=\"http://twitter.com/$1\">@$1</a>", $text);

            $out  .='<li>' . $text . '</li>';

            };

            $out  .='</ul>';

            echo $out;

    ?>
```

Comment: Try **error_reporting(E_ALL)** and you can find yourself

Comment: ... or check your PHP/Apache error log.

Comment: Try to set certain lines of code in comment and see if the page still doesn't work